# $ \int_{2}^{3} \frac{1}{\log_e x} \mathrm dx $

Tags: integration, logarithms

The value of integral $ \int_{2}^{3} \frac{1}{\log_e x} \mathrm dx $

a.) is less than $2$

b.) is equal to $2$

c.) lies in the interval $(2,3)$

d.) is greater than $3$

My approach: I tried to integrate first by using ILATE rule but its of no use. After that i don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Forget integration techniques. All you need is an estimate. A fairly crude one suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\int_a^b f(x)dx$.  Suppose we know that for all $x\in [a,b]$ that $f(x) \le M$.

Then $\int_a^b f(x)dx \le \int_a^b Mdx = M\cdot x|_a^b = M(b-a)$

And if we know that $f(x) \ge L$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ then $\int_a^b f(x)dx \ge \int_ab Ldx= L\cdot x|_a^b = L(b-a)$.

And therefore:  $L(b-a) \le \int_a^b f(x) dx \le M(b-a)$.

Now a big hint:

> $1 < \sqrt e < 2 < e < 3 < e^2$[1] so $\ln 1 < \ln \sqrt e < \ln 2 < \ln e < \ln 3 < \ln e^2$ an $0 < \frac 12 < \ln 2 < 1 < \ln 3 < 2$[2] and so $2 > \frac 1{\ln 2} > 1> \frac 1{\ln 3} > \frac 12$.

And now the answer

> If $2 \le x \le 3$ then $\frac 12 < \frac 1{\ln x} < 2$ so $\frac 12 =\int_2^3\frac 12 dx<\int_2^3 \frac 1{\ln x} dx < \int_2^3 2dx = 2$.

=================================

[1]

> We know $2 < e < 3$ so $e^2 > 2^2=4 > 3$.  And $\sqrt e < \sqrt 3 < 2$ and $\sqrt e > \sqrt 2 > 1$.

[2]  I am talking it for granted that you know that $\ln x$ is an increasing function[3].

[3]

> Actually, as $\ln x$ is increasing then $\frac 1{\ln x}$ is decreasing and my argument about $L(b-a) \le \int_a^b f(x) dx\le M(b-a)$ can be made a lot cleaner for a decreasing function.  If $f(x)$ is a decreasing function then $M = f(a)$ and $L =f(b)$ and  so $$f(b)[b-a] < \int_a^{b} f(x) dx < f(a)[b-a]$$ (and if $b-a = 1$, well, boy howdy ..... $$f(b) < \int_a^{b} f(x) dx  < f(a)$$ ... is pretty darned clean).

Comment: thank you. Its a good explanation.

Comment: (+1) for the well constructed, clear and concise solution.

Comment: fully Explained answer but why so many hint boxes?

Comment: Only one is a hint box.  The other is an answer box.  And the other two are footnote boxes.  Neither the hint box nor the answer box should b read until the OP works on their own.  The footnotes should be read as the subject comes up and.... well .... the third foot note like the second doesn't need to be hidden I guess.  But the first does.

Comment: On second thought it does..... Irritatingly I can't tie hint  boxes to link and reveal simultaneously with others.  And although there is probably a way to put like breaks in a single quote box I haven't figured out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you use an approximation technique.
In this question, a simple approximation would work.

Since we are given $$\int_{2}^{3}\frac{1}{\ln x}$$ it is previously known to use that, integration can be interpretted as summation of areas.

So now, $\large{\frac{1}{ln 3}}= \small{0.910}$ and $\large{\frac{1}{ln 2}}= \small{1.442}$

we can say that the area lies between $(3-2)\times0.910$ and $(3-2)\times 1.442$

For reference,

[image]

The shaded portion is our accurate required answer. And we have already found our approximated range which is consistent.